# Trouble with number_format PHP

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with this line:

```
print "PRINT for row[EUROS]: " .$row['EUROS'] . "<BR>";
print "PRINT for the format: " .number_format($row['EUROS'], 2, ',', '') ."<BR>";
```

The number is **24,7**, but it shows me **24.00**. I thought number_format would help me with the **,** separator, but it doesn't work...

[image: The mistake]

Any idea on how to take the decimal values?

Comment: did you print $row['EUROS'] before number_format to see its value?

Comment: Yes, it's 24,7. I print page on an edit.

Comment: `echo number_format(24.7, 2, ',', '')` output `24,70` Are you sure of your input variable ?

Comment: what is your exact input and output format you expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `str_replace(',', '.', $row['EUROS'])` to replace comma with dot and then use `number_format`. Cheers!

The third parameter in number_format is the dec_point wich separates decimal point in the output string but not in the input.

Answer (score 4):

`"24,7"` is not a number, it's a string with a comma in it, which is not a *well formed number*. The best meaning PHP can extract from that is `24`, with the rest being garbage.

Don't have numbers with commas in them.

Comment: The problem is that I import thousands of numbers in string format from a data base and, obviously, is not a good idea to change the ',' manually for all of them...

Comment: Then replace the comma with a period automatically. Fact is, numbers don't have commas in them in PHP.